# Can I backup a dovecot account via rsync?

Tags: rsync, dovecot

I would like to backup a remote dovecot account to my local disc.

The docs explain a tool which seems to support only a "push", not a "pull" way of backup: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/Sync

My question: Why not backup a remote dovecot IMAP account via rsync?

Which rsync options should I use?

I have full root-access to the remote server.

Comment: It is ok if you down vote my question. But please leave a comment why you do so. Thank you :-)

Comment: I downvoted it for misunderstanding the applications and tools being used, and for the "Which rsync options should I use?" question. We do not do research for you.

Answer (score 5):

> I would like to backup a remote dovecot account to my local disc.

A "dovecot account" is an IMAP/POP3 mailbox. So you'll need to pull down all the mail using an appropriate IMAP/POP3 tool. Never fear! Dovecot has such tools, as you've found out.

> The docs explain a tool which seems to support only a "push", not a
>   "pull" way of backup: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/Sync

That's just the "sync" part of the utility which merges mailboxes and their items without any loss. You can also use the `doveadm-backup` tool (Which is just `doveadm backup` which pulls items from one mailbox into another, and deletes conflicts in the destination.

> My question: Why not backup a remote dovecot IMAP account via rsync?

Because you're now dealing with two separate layers. Dovecot is an IMAP server and to backup an IMAP account you'll probably be looking to appropriate IMAP utilities. `rsync` is a filesystem based tool. *Can* you use rsync to backup your IMAP accounts? Sure! But you'd be backing up filesystem level information about the IMAP application and its data. Make sure you know where to look and how to recover the data appropriately.

> Which rsync options should I use?

[The ones that work.](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

Comment: The link to the rsync man page does not help.

Comment: Why doesn't the man page help ?

Comment: @guettli Why not? Have you read it? If so, did you try using the options that fulfill your backup requirements?

Comment: I am a hero, I take gcc and code it myself. I don't need the rsync man page.

Comment: You are sir, a living legend can I touch you and feel your greatness ... oh no you are a developer I will have my intelligence sucked out and become a DevOPs

Comment: The question is pertinent in my case. I do want to backup my Dovecot Maildirs using rsync because of many reasons(e.g. home dir backup). Is it Ok if I stop dovecot and postfix before running rsync and restart it after ?

Comment: Answering my own question: See : http://www.agix.com.au/restoring-emails-from-backups-dovecot-thunderbird/